# How to fix Angular app to work in Chrome again?

Tags: angular, google-chrome, windows-10

I have an Angular 5 application running on Windows 10. Suddenly my app open
with smaller fonts. This problem doesn't happen in Firefox nor ie.

It was working correctly till now and I don't think I've done something to cause this.
All other website in other Chrome tabs show correctly.
Any idea what can be the issue ?

Comment: `CTRL + mouse scroll up` ?

Comment: yes, but I thought I have bigger problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably played with the screen zoom. Try reset it by using `CTRL + 0`